# Compare 2 strings even if capital letters are included

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I have a question about an if statement.

```
    if($_POST['billing_first_name'] == $tet['data']['0']['first_name']) {
    } 
    else 
    {
run code    
    }
```

This code compares a string that it gets from a form with an already existing string.

It works. But when i dont add a capital letter, it runs the code after all.

So for example if i compare String with String it doesnt run the code (which is what i want) But when i compare string with String it runs the code (which i dont want) Only because theres no capital letter included at the beginning. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: use `strtolower()` on both strings then compare http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

Comment: `==` is case-sensitive, [`strcasecmp`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) is not.

Comment: When you say it runs the code is it the if block or the else. `"Tommy" == "tommy"` should put you in the `else`

Comment: The else @nerdlyist

Comment: So this is working fine. If you want the code to run on True you put it in the opening if block. If you want it to run when false you put it in the else.

Comment: @cmorrissey if(strtolower($_POST['billing_first_name']) == strtolower($tet['data']['0']['first_name']))  something like this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it thanks to cmorrissey.

using strlower on both variables allows me to compare 2 strings no matter if there are capital letters inside one of the strings.

```
 if(strtolower($_POST['billing_first_name']) == strtolower($tet['data']['0']['first_name'])) {
    //do nothing
    }else {
    //run code
    }
```

Comment: The answer/comments by @nerdlyist are still relevant. If you only want to run the code when the compared strings are not equal, you can use the `!=` operator. Then you won't have an empty clause. Also, if this is your solution, you should mark it as the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment the code is running fine it is an understanding of which block your are in.

`if(condition){//code}`  will only run code when the condition is true ie

```
if("String" == "String"){echo "foo";} // will echo foo
if("string" == "String"){echo "foo";} // will not echo foo
```

In order to run code when false you add an else

```
// Will echo foo
if("String" == "String"){
    echo "foo";
} else {
    echo "bar";
}

// Will echo bar
if("string" == "String"){
    echo "foo";
} else {
    echo "bar";
}
```

A trick to getting ifs to execute when something is false is to use the `!` (meaning not)

```
// Will echo bar
if("String" != "String"){
    echo "foo";
} else {
    echo "bar";
}

// Will echo foo
if("string" != "String"){
    echo "foo";
} else {
    echo "bar";
}
```

Comment: I was trying to run the code if the 2 strings im comparing were equal, but when i added one with a capital letter and one without the code would run. i solved it now.

Comment: @Kevin.a you should share how you solved it. It helps the community know this question is answered.